# How should I understand this "that" clause?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, conjunctions

The following sentence is from an [article](http://athens.indymedia.org/local/webcast/uploads/frankfurt__harry_-_on_bullshit.pdf) of Harry Frankfurt who is a professor from Princeton University:

> It must be part of the point of saying that humbug is "short of lying," **that** while it has some of the distinguishing characteristics of lies, there are others that it lacks.

How should I understand the second "that" (in bold) here? Does it refer to "it" in the sentence or is it an object of the word "saying"? How should I understand this sentence?

Comment: Why down vote? Is my question too stupid? Could the one who did it provide a suggestion for improvement of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple ***[Extraposition](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/extrapos.html)***.

However, it's not correct to say that the boldfaced *that* **refers** to *it* in the sentence. 
In fact, **neither** *that* nor *it* has any reference at all. 
They're both function words; *that* is a complementizer which introduces a tensed subject [Complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) clause, while *it* is a dummy subject introduced by Extraposition to keep the subject slot open.

This sentence comes from something like the following, with all pronouns expanded:

- *That while humbug has some of the distinguishing characteristics of lies, there are other characteristics that humbug lacks must be part of the point of saying that humbug is "short of lying".*

This is even less clear, which is why Extraposition moves the entire subject

- *that while humbug has some of the distinguishing characteristics of lies, there are other characteristics that humbug lacks*

(leaving *it* behind as the the dummy subject) to the end of the verb phrase

- *must be part of the point of saying that humbug is "short of lying"*

where it can be parsed more easily. Well, **somewhat** more easily, anyway. This is a good place to use *the fact that,* and to emphasize the contrast between *some* and *others* to make the parallels clear.

- *The fact that humbug has **some** of the distinguishing characteristics of lies, but lacks **others**, must be part of the point of saying that humbug is "short of lying".*

Comment: Hmm, it's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

"That" attaches to "the point" here.  So the reason for the saying that humbug is short of lying is **that** it shares some but not all the characteristics of lies.

Comment: What's "it" here then?

Comment: The first _that_ does. But the second one is the one that's boldfaced.

Comment: In this case, it is "humbug".

Comment: @john lawler The second bolded "that" attaches to "the point", the  first forms part of a phrase with "saying".