# What is the difference between seems like /seems that/seems?

Tags: word-choice, sense-verbs

Is there any difference between these expressions?

> It seems like they have not completed the task yet.
>
> It seems that they have not completed the task yet.
>
> It seems  they haven't completed the task yet.

Comment: _seems_ is just short for _seems that_. But the body of your question is not the same as the title.

Comment: Two vs. three has been covered many times by now, the canonical question being [Are there rules about using “that” to join two clauses?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Comment: No, it's about _seem_, which is a prototypic [A-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) verb and has very complex syntax, with dummies and deletions.

Answer (score 11):

In terms of meaning, there is no difference between the second and third sentences.

> It seems that they have not completed the task yet.
>
> It seems they haven't completed the task yet.

The word *that* is not necessary to be there when it is used as a conjunction to  introduce a subordinate clause expressing a statement or hypothesis.

> I hope that I can fly.
>
> I hope I can fly.

As suggested by RegDwighт♦, you can read more about it [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses).

---

If you care *a lot* about the details,

there is actually a *very small* difference between the first and second/third sentences.

> It seems like they have not completed the task yet.
>
> It seems (that) they have not completed the task yet.

The word *like* here is used as a preposition:

> **like**
>
> having the same characteristics or qualities as; similar to

and the interesting thing is, the word *seem* has the definition:

> **seem**
>
> give the impression or sensation of being something or having a particular quality

So when you use the second/third sentence

> It seems (that) they have not completed the task yet.

you are giving a hypothesis as you are saying that

> It gives an impression that they have not completed the task yet.

which shows that you are not totally sure if they have not completed the task.

Using the sentence with the word *like* would indicate that you are **even less sure** if they have not completed the task.

> It gives an impression that is similar to that they have not completed the task.

Answer (score 4):

***Seem*** is a very odd verb, and participates in a number of odd constructions.

First, notice that *seem* means the same as (and has much the same syntax as) *[appear](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/276076/15299)*, which is a visual sense verb that's been generalized to all senses. *Seem* has been bleached of most of its verbal meaning, and now is merely used to add a touch of dubiosity to a judgement, like an adverb or a modal.

- *They're rioting in Africa.*
- *They seem to be rioting in Africa.*
- *Possibly they are rioting in Africa.*
- *It's cold out.*
- *It appears to be cold out.*
- *It might be cold out.*

The syntax of *seem*, however, is a mare's nest, and it's an old mare.

*Seem* originally meant *think*, and in Middle English dialects both had cliticized first person dative-subject constructions marking the experiencer subject as *me*:

- ***Methinks** the truth should live from age to age*. (*Richard III*: III.i)
- ***Mee seemes** hee makes it something more excellent then Faith it self* (Sclater, 1629)

But as the Dative Subject construction died out in English, *think* and *seem* moved in different syntactic directions, and today they don't behave at all similarly.

*Think* became a stative transitive verb with experiencer subject in the nominative, not the dative, taking a tensed *that*-[complement](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/complementtypes.pdf) object.

- *I **think** that I shall never see a poem lovely as a tree.*

*Seem*, on the other hand, became a intransitive flip verb with the experienced phenomenon as the **subject**, not the object; and a deletable dative experiencer, expressed if necessary as a prepositional phrase with *to*. It thus takes a subject complement, not object.

- *That I shall never see a poem lovely as a tree **seems** (to me).*

Of course, this is a terrible sentence because the verb, which means practically nothing, is the last word in the sentence (since *to me* is usually understood), in the place where the most important word belongs. English fixes this by [extraposing](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60093/15299) the whole subject clause at the cost of leaving behind a [dummy *it* subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73687/15299).

- *It **seems** (to me) that I shall never see a poem lovely as a tree .*

*Seem*, however, unlike *think*, can also take infinitive complements, and that's where [A-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) comes in. The awkward but grammatical sentences

- *[For it to be raining|For there to be a unicorn in the garden] seems (to me).*
- *[For them to be tired|For him to be ready to go] seems (to me).*

get transformed by A-Raising into the much more palatable

- *It seems to be raining | There seems to be a unicorn in the garden.*
- *They seem to be tired | He seems to be ready to go.*

*Seems like* is just a variant on *seems*, and *that* is just a complementizer for the tensed complement.

Comment: Would you say there is a difference in nuance between "seems like" and "seems"?