# 'There seem' or 'there seems' + usage of the word 'seem'

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs, modal-verbs

First, I have a question "How words 'seem' and 'there' are used together?"

Which is correct:

- There seem ...

or

- There seems ...

Then, I'm am interested in general constructions with the word 'seem'.

What are common mistakes people make when they use this word?

Comment: There ***seem*** to be ***multiple*** issues here. To take just one, there ***seems*** to be ***a*** complete lack of context.

Comment: True. However, there seem to be two questions involved: (1) [_There_-Insertion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/thereins.vbs.html), and (2) the [syntax of the verb _seem_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/97613/15299). Plus their interaction when they occur together.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Singular:

> There is a problem with the car.
>   A problem seems to be afflicting the car.
>   There seems to be a problem afflicting the car.
>   It seems to be a minor problem.

Plural:

> There are multiple problems with the car.
>   Multiple problems seem to be affecting the car.
>   There seem to be multiple problems affecting the car.
>   They seem to be minor problems.

Do not confuse with:

> She seems to have problems with her car.

vs

> They seem to have a problem with their car.

Comment: Seems about right to me! :)

Comment: Are the rules the same for the word "appear"? "There appear to be problems", etc.