# "it seems" vs. "it seems that"

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between using "it seems" and "it seems that"

For example:

> "It seems that automatic restart is not happening now"
>
> "It seems automatic restart is not happening now"

Which one is correct?  Or are they both?

Comment: Tensed _that_-complements like _(that) automatic restart is not happening now_ can delete the optional "_(that)_ unless the [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Complements.pdf) begins the sentence, in which case the _that_ is required: _That you left early is unfortunate_ but **You left early is unfortunate*.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [very similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97541/what-is-the-difference-between-seems-like-seems-that-seems) here on EL&U. Quoting the relevant answer from here-

In terms of meaning, there is no difference between these sentences:

> It seems that they have not completed the task yet.
>
> It seems they haven't completed the task yet.

The word **that** is not necessary to be there when it is used as a conjunction to introduce a subordinate clause expressing a statement or hypothesis.

Comment: It's not necessary (though it's almost always possible) for **any** complement clause (no matter what it expresses), **except** when the complement clause comes at the beginning of the sentence. (BTW, the clause "The word _that_ is not necessary to be there" is ungrammatical, since _necessary_ does not allow [A-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).)

Comment: Yes, I believe that condition(complement clause beginning at the sentence) has been mentioned in one of the comments below the original question, so I didn't point it out(again). And, as for your second observation, yes- you're right. The grammatical construction isn't correct, but, then again, those aren't my words. I'm merely quoting from the answer given in the possible duplicate question.

Comment: Which is why I distrust previous answers that get linked to by supposedly "duplicate" questions. They often contain incorrect information, and they often disagree.

Comment: @JohnLawler It's not entirely true that the complementizer *that* can be omitted "for **any** complement clause". It is strongly preferred if verb and complement are not adjacent: ? *I realized with sadness in my heart [ _ he had done it]*. It is almost categorically required if there is fronting in the complement clause: ??? *I think [_ on him, no coat looks good]*. It is obligatory if the complement clause is fronted: * *[ _ Mary cheated on Bill] upset him*. (Here, *_* is a position for *that*.)

Comment: Deletions of grammatical particles like complementizers are normal when they're predictable, under prototype circumstances. In situations far from the prototype, like separation and fronting, optional deletions of any kind are fraught with ambiguities. At least.