# What type of word allows raising?

Tags: grammar

I've come across a comment in [“it seems” vs. “it seems that”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187348/it-seems-vs-it-seems-that) and I am uncertain as to what type of word allows raising.

> It's not necessary (though it's almost always possible) for any complement clause (no matter what it expresses), except when the complement clause comes at the beginning of the sentence. (BTW, the clause "The word *that* is not necessary to be there" is ungrammatical, since *necessary* does not allow A-Raising.) – John Lawler Jul 27 '14 at 17:58

Comment: Do you mean **A-raising**?

Comment: @JohnLawler has a paper on his website: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf

Comment: Raising of the subject occurs in, say, *My mom is likely [ _ to come]*, where *My mom* is the subject of *likely* as well as of embedded *come*. You can't do that with *necessary*: * *My mom is necessary [ _ to come]*. Raising needs to be diagnosed with a battery of syntactic tests.