# Is 'seem' always a linking verb?

Tags: linking-verbs

The verb 'seem' is a specimen linking verb, as in:

> (1) He seems a nice guy.

But it can have a clause as its complement, as in:

> (2) He seems *to be a nice guy*. [to-infinitive clause]
>
> (3) It seems *that he is a nice guy*. [that-clause]

In (2) or (3) or both, is the verb 'seem' still a linking verb or something else?

Answers to [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97541/what-is-the-difference-between-seems-like-seems-that-seems), don't specifically say whether the verb 'seem' as in (2) or (3) can be classified as a linking verb or not.

If you or anyone can locate anything close to a possible answer to my question in the link, please let me know.

Comment: (1) is essentially the same as (2) *He seems [to be] a nice guy*.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're trying to say by that. I mean, who doesn't know they are "essentially the same"? Do you mean therefore that it's a linking verb in (2)? If not, the question still stands.

Comment: I don't know much about grammar, so take this with a grain of salt. In (1) *seems* is a linking verb and *a nice guy* is a predicative complement; in (2) *seems* is a catenative verb and *to be a nice guy* is a catenative complement, *to be* being the linking verb. I don't know what to tell you about (3), except that it features an it-transposition. More [here](http://www.grin.com/en/e-book/52296/catenatives-or-complex-vp-the-debate-about-specific-verbs-in-english) and [here](http://www.uam.es/proyectosinv/woslac/Amaya/Mendikoetxea%20%282003%29%20English%20and%20the%20Good%20Gramarian.pdf).

Comment: So according to the link above, in (3) *that he is a nice guy* is the notional subject. *Seems* isn't a linking verb simply because there's nothing to link.

Comment: @Yay The judgment that _that he is a nice guy_ in (3) is the notional subject is untenable, I think. If it is, then you should be able to replace _It_ with that "notional subject" without rendering (3) ungrammatical, which it does. *_That he is a nice guy seems._

Comment: JK2: The grammar behind "seem" is explained in detail in the second answer of the question linked.

Comment: @JK2 Define "linking verb" ;) If you can then I'm sure you'll have your answer.

Comment: @curiousdannii My question sort of asks the exact definition of a linking verb. So to ask me to define it would be tantamount to asking me to answer my own question. I mean, if I knew the answer, why would I even ask? :)

Comment: @JK2 What I meant was that in (1), the *to be* is simply elided.

Comment: @Yay Does that "grammar behind _seem_ explained in the second answer" tell you whether it's a linking verb in (2) and (3)? If so, why don't you tell me here in the comment section? Do you even figure that out yourself? I doubt that.

Comment: Nope, but it does explain why *that he is a nice guy* could be considered a notional subject in (3). If that is true, I don't see how it could be a linking verb. Btw, I find this question really interesting and I hope it won't get closed. I agree with you that the alleged duplicate doesn't come anywhere close to answering your question, but being condescendent won't get you anywhere. People don't respond favorably to rudeness here. Anyway, if it eventually gets closed, you can also raise the issue on Meta.

Comment: @Yay I thought you were one of those who voted to close. Apparently not. Sorry for my misunderstanding. And I wasn't condescending or rude. 'Dumbfounded' or 'frustrated' might be the word.

Comment: @Yay I don't understand how the that-clause is anything like "a notional subject" or "an extraposed subject" or "a postponed subject" (whatever you want to call it). Like I said in my earlier comment, in (3) you can't replace the grammatical subject _It_ with the that-clause without making it ungrammatical. (The fact that the prof. says otherwise in that link only makes his answer less reliable.) So it's undeniable that the that-clause in (3) is a complement of the verb 'seem'. So the only remaining question may be whether a linking verb can have a clause as a complement or not.

Comment: It's an impersonal construction, not extraposition.  See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002) starting on page 961 for some discussion of why you might choose not to analyze it as extraposition.

Comment: @snailboat That's what I'm talking about. :)

Comment: You still haven't given us a definition or link to a definition for "linking verb". Do that and I'd be happy to vote to reopen it.

Comment: @curiousdannii If the lack of the definition of 'linking verb' was the reason for closing this question, why was it marked as 'duplicate'? Seriously, I just don't get it.

Comment: People can vote for multiple reasons, but it only shows the reason with the most close votes.

Comment: @curiousdannii And the reason with the most close votes doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

A *linking verb* is one that licenses a predicate nominative, a noun or adjectival phrase that gives an equivalent for the subject or describes the subject respectively.  The predicative nominative differs in a number of ways from an object, which is a noun phrase that receives the action of a transitive verb.  We can use these differences to determine whether *seems* is a linking verb:

- Can *seems* take an *adjectival* predicate nominative?  Yes, we can have the following characterization of him:

> He **seems** *nice*.

Can't do that with a transitive verb:

> *She saw nice.

- How many things are involved?  For a linking verb, the answer is one:

  > He **seems** like a nice guy.

There's only the subject *he*, who happens to be a nice guy.  In

> She saw a nice guy

there are two people, the observer and the observed.

- Linking verbs cannot be transposed into a passive construction.  Will this work with *seems*?  No:

> *It **is seemed** to be a nice guy by him.

Contrast this with

> A nice guy was seen by her.

*Seems* seems to pass the syntactic tests for a linking verb.